# how to use glm's operator== in stl algorithms?

Tags: opengl, stl

Is it possible to use the operators defined in glm::gtx::comparison in stl algorithms?

Specifically i have this code:

```
std::vector<glm::ivec3> vecA, vecB;    // vectors with content
bool result = std::equal(vecA.begin(), vecA.end(), vecB.begin());
```

This by default fails cause operator== can't be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an [open bug](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/ogl-math/ticket/21) apparently.

Comment: ah ok ... should have considered that option ;)

Answer (score 3):

Only a few years late, but I wanted to share my fix.
I needed a comparator function for std::map and std::set.

After a bit of tinkering, I found the solution to have the following code

```
#ifndef __UTIL_GLM__
#define __UTIL_GLM__
#include "glm/vec2.hpp"
namespace glm{
  template <typename T, precision P>
  bool operator<(const tvec2<T, P>& a,const tvec2<T, P>& b)
  {
    return (a.x < b.x || (a.x == b.x && a.y < b.y));
  }
};
#endif
```

in a header file util_glm.hpp and include it where ever the comparator was needed with

```
#include "util_glm.hpp"
```

I am sure a similar solution can be done for glm::ivec3

Answer (score 0):

You can #include equal_operator.hpp, in the virtrev/ directory.

Comment: "virtrev/equal_operator.hpp" is included by "glm/ext.hpp" so this doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use `glm::vec3` in a `std::set<>`, I implemented the following overload in the **type_vec3.inl**:

```
template <typename T> 
    GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER bool operator<
    (
        tvec3<T> const & v1, 
        tvec3<T> const & v2
    )
    {
        if(v1.x == v2.x && v1.y == v2.y && v1.z < v2.z) return true;
        if(v1.x == v2.x && v1.y < v2.y) return true;
        if(v1.x < v2.x) return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Unfortunately I don't know how to implement it without change the glm code.

This implementation consider x axis more relevant than y axis and y axis more relevant then z concerning smaller than. It's very simple to change the code to make any other axis more relevant.

The `==` operator is already implemented.